# How to get notified when a UIViewController appears?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to be notified when for example every window/viewcontroller has called `viewDidLoad`? Like a viewcontrollers tracker. I don't want to repeat code too much. Thanks

Comment: You can create your own class and inherit from `UIViewController`, override the `viewDidLoad` method. Even if you'll need to do some extra stuff in the `viewDidLoad` just make sure that you call the `super.viewDidLoad`

Comment: Consider that *when `UIViewController` appears* is not equal to *has called `viewDidLoad`*. There are three stages: `viewDidLoad` (called once), `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` (can be called multiple times)

Comment: Are you looking for a generic function which should be called automatically whenever any controller loads?

Comment: I'm looking for something as simple as plug-play (like a notification or extension), I currently have hundreds of classes and some solutions will be just too much to do if I want to add or even remove it.

Comment: I don't think if there is any method to achieve this thing. People could misuse this functionality while writing library.

Comment: you should add  "I'm looking for something as simple as plug-play (like a notification or extension), I currently have hundreds of classes and some solutions will be just too much to do if I want to add or even remove it"

It will help you to get a batter solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another method that doesn't require any overriding of all classes inside of your project to inherit from `BaseViewController`. That's **method swizzling**.
Method swizzling is the process of changing the implementation of an existing selector at runtime. Basically, it is just changing the functionality of a method at runtime.

So, you can do the following:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static let classInit: Void = {
        let originalSelector = #selector(viewDidLoad)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(proj_viewDidLoad)
        swizzling(UIViewController.self, originalSelector, swizzledSelector)
    }()

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling

    @objc func proj_viewDidLoad() {
        self.proj_viewDidLoad()

        let viewControllerName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
        /// Whatever you want in here
        print("viewDidLoad: \(viewControllerName)")
    }
 }

private let swizzling: (AnyClass, Selector, Selector) -> () = { forClass, originalSelector, swizzledSelector in
    guard
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, originalSelector),
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(forClass, swizzledSelector)
    else { return }
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
}
```

After that, you need to activate it in `AppDelegate` this way:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {   
    override init() {
        super.init()
        UIViewController.classInit
    }
    /// ... the rest
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

You may create a `BaseViewController` and inherit from it every other view controller that you want to observe.

```
 class BaseViewController:UIViewController{
   func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad()
     print("inherit all viewControllers with this class")
     print("perform your work you wanted to do")
  }
}

class firsViewController: BaseViewController{
   func  viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
      print("I will call baseViewController too")
  }
}
class SecondViewController: BaseViewController{
    func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
      print("I will call baseViewController too")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a base view controller, extend all your controllers with it instead of UIViewController like `class MyViewController: BaseViewController {`, then you can do anything in the base's `viewDidLoad` which will run for all controller's having them all do `super.viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do this:

You can create Global class for ex : you have your ViewController class with the code in and then you create subclasses of this instead of UIViewController as concept of inheritance mentioned in another answer.

Or you can also create extension , protocols and class with class methods and you can use that class shared instance to every where you want in view controller.